# Numbering tables A1, A2, etc in Latex

Tags: floats, numbering

I have main tables and appendix tables in my paper. I would like to number the appendix tables "A1", "A2", "A3", etc OR, at the very least, re-start the table numbering at 1 in the appendix. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? In fact, please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) of your current setup so it can be replicated. It will speed things up and get answers your way much quicker.

Answer (score 62):

The documentclass might provide more elegant options. But the following should do the trick, inserted where the appendix starts:

```
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
```

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Do you know the best way how to get this done in `scrreprt`? Can you also recommend the hack for this class? Thanks.

Comment: Background: It produces a dot after each table which doesn't belong there. It even adds that dot to all my tables, also out of the appendix

Comment: @TomM: In the KOMA-Script classes `\tableformat` can be redefined without `\autodot`: `\renewcommand*{\tableformat}{\tablename~\thetable}`

Answer (score 22):

A slightly more robust solution than that proposed by @HeikoOberdiek is to use `\Alph` to format the name of the current appendix.

For example, I have multiple appendix chapters (A, B, etc.), and otherwise have my table names formatted with a period between chapter number and table number, so the following update of `\thetable` continues this convention through the appendix:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
```

In your case, **assuming the appendix is a chapter** (a MWE would help), you could just use the following, without a period:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{chapter}\arabic{table}}
```

**If your appendix is a section,** you would want something like this:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}
```

Comment: One still also needs to execute `\setcounter{table}{0}` at the start of each appendix if appendices are section-level rather than chapter-level dividers.

Comment: In the documentclass I'm using, table numbering is chapter-specific, and since each appendix is delimited using a chapter, the counter is reset automatically.  It seems this may not be the case for @user2472081, so yes, they would need to do that.  As mentioned previously, a MWE would help clarify such things.

Comment: For me this command only worked when I changed `chapter` to `section`: `\setcounter{table}{0}` & `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}`

Comment: That is because you used `\section{}` for the appendices and not `\chapter{}`...