# Change Appendix table numbering

Tags: tables, numbering, article, appendix

I am using `article` atm and trying to implement a short appendix at the end of the document. For testing, the appendix should just contain a single table.

I use the following code:

```
\section*{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}
\setcounter{table}{0}
```

So I am using a section to create the appendix. What I want to achieve is the table labelled as A.1, the next one as A.2, etc. What is the right way to do it? In my document, I have many sections, and as a result the labelling for the first table in the appendix is "Table G1". It should be: "A.1". My used solution is from here: [Numbering tables A1, A2, etc in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118606/numbering-tables-a1-a2-etc-in-latex)
Any hints highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried adding `\setcounter{section}{1}` under the `\setcounter{table}{0}`?

Comment: @Jon no, I tried `\setcounter{section}{0}` as for the tables, but that didnt work :) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a MWE which gives table tiles as A.number. This uses the `caption` package to add a custom label format called `AppendixTables` in the example below. If you want to change the title for all your appendix Tables it can be done by changing the `A.#2` in the label format. `#1` (not shown) would be the text from the `\caption{}` command in the table if you wanted to include text that way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{AppendixTables}{A.#2}

\begin{document}
\section*{Appendix}
\captionsetup{labelformat=AppendixTables}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{}
\center
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
&\\
\hline
&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{}
\center
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
&\\
\hline
&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This results in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - this worked well, only the "A." doesn't get added in the table directory. How can this be added, too?