# The usual method doesn't let me number appendix tables as A1, A2, etc

Tags: numbering, appendix

I would like to number my appendix tables A1, A2, and so forth. To do this, I used the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118606/numbering-tables-a1-a2-etc-in-latex) and tried writing

```
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
```

before I write `\begin{appendices}`. However, this seems to be completely ignored, and doesn't change the numbering.

Here is a shortened version of my Latex code (I have erred on the side of inclusion since I'm not sure what is causing the issue):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, hyperref, amsmath,amsfonts, bm, eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,mathtools,natbib, xcolor,setspace,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,subfigure,array, parskip, bbm, csquotes, multirow, booktabs,caption}
    
\urlstyle{same}
    
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\hyper@natlinkbreak[2]{#1}
\makeatother

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}

\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\normalem

\onehalfspacing

\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}

\newenvironment{myquote}%
  {\list{}{\leftmargin=0.3in\rightmargin=0in}\item[]}%
  {\endlist}

\begin{document}

Here is some random text.

Here is a figure.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{graph_a}
\caption{An example graph}
\label{fig:x cubed graph}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\newpage

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}

\begin{appendices}

\section{Another figure...}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{graph_a}
\caption{An example graph}
\label{fig:x cubed graph}
\end{figure}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For figures you need to add

```
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
```

[image: a]

Comment: Of course! Guess I should have been able to figure that out...